# VB.NET scroll to top webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, browser

**I'm almost done with my project :)**

i want to scroll the page to top evrey second

```
    WebBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = True
    WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollTop
```

it not work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

timer1.interval = 1000

Timer1.Tick:

```
wb.navigate("javascript:window.scroll(0,150);")
```